# Bokeh (Python) Figure.vbar() vs Bar()

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm just starting to take a look at Bokeh for data visualization and am wondering the advantage/disadvantage to using `Figure.vbar()` vs `Bar()` if someone could clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bar` is from the high level **Charts** interface.  It gives you quick, easy access to bar charts with limited control.

`vbar` is from the mid level **Plotting** interface and gives you more control over the layout of your bar chart.  Alternatives to `vbar` would be `rect` and `quad`, both from the **Plotting** interface.  They give a few distinctive options for bar shape, location, etc.

> `bar` is much easier if you don't need to do anything fancy.  If you decide you want more control over your plot (like `HoverTool` etc) you will have to instantiate a `Figure` and use one of it's methods.

---

`bar` docs [Here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.0/docs/reference/charts.html#bar)

and

`vbar` docs [Here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure.vbar)

I use both, depending on my needs.

Comment: Great answer! I would like to add, that `vbar` accepts the `source` parameter, which allows you to dynamically update your histogram with Bokeh Server.